# Spring Integration. How to catch the Custom exception?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

It seems i don't understand some underlying concepts about custom Exceptions handling in Spring Integration(

I need to intercept some of my RuntimeException-derived custom exceptions (thrown from some my Java method) and depending of it's type route the app execution flow to some other route.

I use the Spring Integration version 4.3.10.RELEASE.

To do this i declare the **int:exception-type-router** like this:

```
<int:exception-type-router input-channel="errorChannel" default-output-channel="nullChannel">
        <int:mapping exception-type="com.surr.exception.SurrRoutingException"
                     channel="handleRedirectChannel"/>
        <int:mapping exception-type="com.surr.exception.SurrFatalException"
                     channel="surrChannelMain"/>
        <!-- some more mappings -->
</int:exception-type-router>
```

Channel declaration sample:

```
<int:channel id="handleRedirectChannel"
     datatype="com.surr.exception.SurrRoutingException">
      <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
```

After my Exception throwing i cannot step into related channels. What i'm doing wrong? Maybe i've missed smth in the app initial setup?

Thanks a lot for any assist.

**Update**
After notes from Artem i made some changes described below:

1. Introduced additional error channel:

```
<int:channel id="errorChannel1">
        <int:queue capacity="500"/>
</int:channel>
```

2. As the very 1st statement in my message processing chain overrode the 'errorChannel' header:

```
<int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="errorChannel" value="errorChannel1"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

3. Modified the 'int:exception-type-router':

```
<int:exception-type-router input-channel="errorChannel1" default-output-channel="nullChannel">
        <int:mapping exception-type="java.lang.Throwable"
                     channel="handleRedirectChannel"/>
        <int:mapping exception-type="java.lang.RuntimeException"
                     channel="handleRedirectChannel"/>
        <int:mapping exception-type="com.surr.exception.SurrRoutingException"
                     channel="handleRedirectChannel"/>
        <int:mapping exception-type="com.surr.exception.SurrFatalException"
                     channel="surrChannelMain"/>
</int:exception-type-router>
```

4. Changed the declarations of the recipient channels:

```
<int:channel id="handleRedirectChannel">
     <int:queue capacity="50"/>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="surrChannelMain">
     <int:queue capacity="50"/>
</int:channel>
```

5. In my test began to 'listen' the 'errorChannel1' along w/ the 'handleRedirectChannel' channels

So far there is no any tracks of my thrown Exceptions. I suspect there are some more rules exist to catch the Exception but can't figure them out

**One more update**
I've issued my exception manually using MessageBuilder (MessageBuilder.withPayload(new MyExceptionObjectWithNeededArguments).build()) and sent it to the 'errorChannel1'. Still no effect(

**Stack trace**

```
2021-02-17 23:03:48,742  INFO [   task-scheduler-20             ] [] !! IntentsService.prepareMessages
com.azoft.fakturachat.surrogate.exception.SurrogateRoutingException: Got empty intent description by scenario: [default] and tip: [some_unknown_intent]
    at com.azoft.fakturachat.surrogate.IntentsService.fetchIntentDescription(IntentsService.java:84) ~[main/:?]
    at com.azoft.fakturachat.surrogate.IntentsService.lambda$prepareMessages$0(IntentsService.java:58) ~[main/:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4717) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4725) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at com.azoft.fakturachat.surrogate.IntentsService.prepareMessages(IntentsService.java:59) ~[main/:?]
    at com.azoft.fakturachat.surrogate.IntentsService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d29d5141.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.azoft.fakturachat.aspect.LoggingAspect.logMethod(LoggingAspect.java:31) [main/:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor131.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629) [spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618) [spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) [spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) [spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.azoft.fakturachat.surrogate.IntentsService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9cfa94da.prepareMessages(<generated>) [main/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:113) [spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129) [spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49) [spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:347) [spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) [spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131) [spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:330) [spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:169) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:128) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.processMessage(ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.java:72) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.support.ExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor.processMessage(ExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor.java:71) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher.transform(HeaderEnricher.java:119) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:89) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:110) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) [spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:194) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:129) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) [spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:129) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) [spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:129) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) [spring-messaging-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.DelayHandler.doReleaseMessage(DelayHandler.java:376) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.DelayHandler.access$500(DelayHandler.java:83) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.DelayHandler$ReleaseMessageHandler.handleMessage(DelayHandler.java:470) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.DelayHandler.releaseMessage(DelayHandler.java:368) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.DelayHandler.access$100(DelayHandler.java:83) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.DelayHandler$1.run(DelayHandler.java:328) [spring-integration-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
2021-02-17 23:03:48,751  INFO [   task-scheduler-20             ] [] <- IntentsService.prepareMessages, procTime=306
```

The 'errorChannel1' channel was introduced only to test this issue. There is no other consumer(s) except this 'exception-type-router'

Exception is 'thrown' in the following way:

```
SurrRoutingException ex1 = new SurrRoutingException(
                MessageFormat.format("Failed to find intent description by scenario: [{0}] and tip: [{1}]",
                    scenario, tip), context);
errorChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(ex1).build());
```

Error channel declaration:

```
private final QueueChannel errorChannel;

@Autowired
public IntentsService(@Qualifier("errorChannel1") QueueChannel errorChannel) 
{
        this.errorChannel = errorChannel;
}
```

Comment: You can and should edit your question to include any info think of that might help others to answer it.  If you could move the info in your comment to your question, that would be better.

Comment: You probably have some error after routing, so would be great to see that in your question

Comment: Actually no. I run my chain in unit-test and at the end of it i try to read the message from channel. Other test w/o exceptions run ok, but this one is failing: routing doesn't happen

Answer (score 1):

I think your confuse is because an `<int:exception-type-router>` can deal with stack trace to track an expected exception down, but `datatype` on the channel is exact type of the payload.

See docs for more info:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#router-implementations-exception-router

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-datatype-channel

I would say you don't need a `datatype` for that `handleRedirectChannel` since you use it only from that router. The point of `datatype` is really to restrict producers for this channel which make sense when our application is complex enough and may work even in distributed state when we can't control producers. It doesn't look like a case for your exception router...

Comment: Hi Artem! Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Unfortunately it didn't help( It seems that interception mechanism is not working at all or it was broken somehow. I'm going to update the initial post to reflect my recent updates.

Comment: Still no clue what is going on with your application. Any chances that you can share a simple project with us to let us to reproduce and play with? That way we can debug your flow and see what is going on.

Comment: It's hard to promise that. Actually i'm working on enterprise app and can't share it of course. Preparing of sample similar project will take some time and now i'm out of the project time limits because of this issue((. Maybe you know some debugging/diagnosing hints helping to find out exactly where & why the messages sent directly to 'errorChannel1' are lost? Thanks for your assist

Comment: You can turn on DEBUG logging level for `org.springframework.integration` category to see how your message travel in the flow. You can set a break point into the `ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter.getChannelKeys()` to see what is going on with your message. You probably have some stack trace in your logs already which you don't share with us to have more info. What you show in your config and explain must just work. We are missing some detail you don't share with us. Perhaps you have more consumers on that `errorChannel1`, so your message travels over there - not to this router. And so on.

Comment: Thank you. In a couple of minutes i'll provide the stacktrace. Rest of things going to check tomorrow morning

Comment: Done w/ stacktrace

Comment: Doesn't look like that stack trace is related somehow to what you show with the router. Unless you are messing up with `SurrogateRoutingException` and `SurrRoutingException`...

Comment: You're right: this is the same things. At the beginning didn't want to paste exact names. My excuses if this was messing(

Comment: I don't know. Probably your `SurrRoutingException` is not a `Throwable`... Because that is the first condition in the `ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter`...

Comment: It is a ```RuntimeException``` actually.

Comment: Ok, anyway thanks a lot for your assist. Tomorrow i'm going to check the rest of your suggestions from your comment above.

Comment: OK. What is going on if you change `default-output-channel="nullChannel"` to something valuable? I mean how about not to ignore unrouted messages, but dump them to some other channel, not null

Comment: It did so. Instead of ```nullChannel``` i used the input channel w/ defined data type (not related to any Throwable). I hoped to catch the type mismatch error or smth like that. But there was nothing. Like a black hole for incoming message w/ Throwable payload

Comment: OK. How does it work if your `errorChannel1` is not a `queue`? What is the point to have all the channels as queues in your app though?

Comment: Because w/o a ```queue``` i can't Autowire the QueueChannel variables in my enterprise & testing code

Comment: Huh? It is just a `MessageChannel` for sending. You need nothing more. The framework takes care for you about the proper subscription if that. More over having it as a default `DirectChannel` you are going to get exception thrown back to your code when you send to that `errorChannel1` and something is wrong in the subscriber for that channel. When it is queue, the handling happens on a different scheduled thread. So, you testing code must block some way to see the processing.

Comment: It blocks in ```.receive() ``` method. Delay vary up to 20 secs

Comment: Yeah... Our discussion may go on forever. That's why it is much easier to have some simple reproducable project from you to play with. The mentioned test would be great, too.

Comment: That's right. Quite tricky stuff( I have other queues in my logic and there everything runs ok. The issue happens when i try to intercept my exception in those ```exception-type-router```. I'll try to prepare everything if fail to debug it somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Artem. Just a quick update. Under debugger the ```ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter.getChannelKeys``` was never called, but it's ```ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter.onInit``` executed properly. Are there any requirements for ```exception-type-router``` to declare it correctly? Can it be 'hidded' somehow?

Comment: `onInit()` is called once in the configuration phase. `getChannelKeys()` is called for every message handled by this endpoint. You can start debugging it from the `handle()` method. That’s why I suggested to change an `errorChannel1` to a direct channel, so you could debug it directly from its `send()` method .

Comment: Hi Artem! I keep debugging it. In this method ```util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator#evaluateExpression(org.springframework.expression.Expression, org.springframework.messaging.Message<?>, java.lang.Class<T>)``` i catch my ```SurrogateRoutingException``` object in ```Exception``` clause (not in ```EvaluationException``` clause). After that this method throws ```MessageHandlingException``` exception. I added this exception type to my ```int:exception-type-router``` but it didn't help. Do you know how can i catch this? It seems i'm a bit closer to the solution. Thank you for assist!

Comment: Doesn’t look like it is related to sending an exception to the channel directly...

Comment: ok. Today i commented out my xml-based ```int:exception-type-router``` and introduced one created via @Router annotation. Still no effect. In logs i see its initialisation but actually it doesn't work. For some reason this SI feature is implicitly disabled in my app and it is hard to determine what is going on under the hood. I have some @Exceptionhandlers but it doesn't looks like it can interfere the app execution flow

Comment: You are mixing too much and side track a little bit. It would be great if you’d provide a simple project to play with. But it indeed must fail as you explain. Probably with baby steps to reproduce you’ll see something else in your project you don’t share with us at the moment

Comment: Hi Artem! I added a comment to this topic. Can you look at it? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you there since that information is not relevant to your question. You claim that your router doesn't work, but we still don't see any evidence of that. If you rely on a default `TaskScheduler`, then it is supplied with an `errorChannel` to catch problems from its tasks. Otherwise only a simple reproducible project can help us to determine the root of cause.

Answer (score 0):

I've returned to this issue again. Didn't make a sample project yet but found some info in docs. "SI error handling": **"The most important thing to understand here is that the messaging-based error handling applies only to exceptions that are thrown by a Spring Integration task that is executing within a TaskExecutor. This does not apply to exceptions thrown by a handler that operates within the same thread as the sender (for example, through a DirectChannel as described earlier in this section)"**.

Maybe here is the problem? My app logic is splitted between different chains and routes and maybe some of them are executed not within TaskExecutor and because of it the global interception is not working? i assume that a single, global-scope interceptor per the whole application is not enough. I'm going to verify this assumption. Thanks!